# selenium scraping content from website into an array

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-ide

I am interested in scraping content from a website and putting it into an array.  Specifically, I am interested in scraping plaintext into an array by identifying the html element the plain text is under.  I am using selenium with Java and I was hoping someone could shed some light on the best way to do this.  I would be scanning in multiple plain text elements and putting them in sequential order, into an array. The plain text would be in html tables and I would need to take a specific section of the table that has the plain text I was interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a rather broad question, but still I'm hoping I can help. I've used `selenium` with `scrapy` library (`python`) for scraping and it worked all very well. If your question is what's the best way to find the text in the `HTML` it is pretty much safe to say that the answer is `XPath`. It is a very simple language designed to extract multiple elements from `html/xml`. Just google for examples and I'm sure you'll get the hang of it. Selenium has quiate a few built-in funcionts for xpath, you'll find plenty of examples